# which of the following must be connected

Tags: general-topology

Suppose A be a connected subset of topology space X, which of the following must be connected?
I.the interior of A
II.the closure of A
III.the complement of A

Comment: what did you tried???

Answer (score 1):

The  union of two "kissing" discs is connected. Its interior is not.

What is the complement of an annulus in the plane?

Answer (score 0):

I and III are not closed in general, while it's true that the closure of a connected subspace is connected.